# jQuery scroll is working on pages it should not work on because of turbolinks

Tags: jquery, turbolinks

```
var paginationscript = function() {
  if($('#infinite-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    $('.pagination').hide();
    $('#load_more_photos').show();
    $('#load_more_photos').on('click', function() {
      var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      $.getScript(url);
      $('#load_more_photos').hide();   
      $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        var url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
        if($(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60 && $.active == 0) {
        $.getScript(url);
        }
      });
    }); 
  }
};
```

So this creates an instagram-like setup where we first hide `'.pagination'` which is used if the user does not have js enabled, showing a `button`.  They click that button and get the next page of photos. Then from there we use `scroll` to add the next pages. This all works fine.

The problem that with turbolinks enabled, it works on completely different parts of the app despite the fact that those pages **do not** contain the element `'#infinite-scrolling'`. Those pages **do have** `$('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')` and that seems to be enough for turbolinks to enable the `scroll` function on those pages!

I tried to wrap the `scroll` function in `if(window.location.pathname == "/photos")` but that still did not help.

**Edit**: I added a script to the other pages `$(window).off('scroll')` and that does stop the scroll from working on those pages, however I would be interested in a better way to go about it.

Comment: Try it once $("body").scroll(function(e){ e.preventDefault()});

Comment: @Mr.HK can you be more specific where this should go in the code? maybe submit as an answer

Comment: Von Heiss Yes sure

Comment: i am not trying to stop scrolling of the page, i am trying to stop the pagination (adding new pages) that occurs from the scrolling.

Comment: You mean to say when people scroll the page pagination enable right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to solve this with the boolean of `if(!(window.location.pathname == "/photos")) {};` thus turning off my scroll function upon leaving the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try it once..

To turn OFF scrolling try this:

```
var current = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(current);
});
```

to reset:

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event cannot be canceled. But you can do it by **canceling** these interaction events:
**Mouse & Touch scroll** and **Buttons** associated with scrolling.

**[For Demo Click Here....](http://output.jsbin.com/xatidu/4/)**

```
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```